# Slow Loading Images on WordPress - How do I speed them up

Tags: wordpress, html, server, web, hosting

I want to have a website page load images faster or where the images don't stop the user from seeing the text on the pages before the images finish loading.

**1.** if I have text on a website page. Does the text render first so the user can see text while the images are still loading?

**2.** If i have 3 mb of images and have my server that is hosting the website render 1.5 and then move the other 1.5mb to something like flickr and have the image source point to flickr, will that be better and load faster.  Or say I just have all the images pull from flickr?

Please help me.

Its a WordPress site, and Clouldflare free cdn does something weird to my theme. So not an option.  I also don't want to lazy load for other reason.

**EDIT :** o yea, if I host all the images on Flickr does that give away link juice (Domain Authority Rank)?

Answer (score 0):

Images do increase overall load time, but they aren't render blocking. The whole page will render (barring render-blocking CSS or Scripts) and images will pop in when they are done. If you want to avoid that flash, you can lazy-load them, or otherwise put the final image's sizes on a container element, so the text is already "moved".

You can't really "Speed Up" image loads. The **best** thing to do is cut down on the number of images, if applicable, and lazy-load any that don't need to be requested initially. The next best thing (and arguably more important overall, I suppose) is to **optimize** your images. There are a handful of WordPress plugins that will do this for you, or you can do it in PhotoShop - and even some image CDN's will do it. This basically means, don't load a 1MB image if you don't have to, for "web display" purposes, you can serve a 200kb image that looks *almost* as good.

A side point, you can "speed them up" a little by having them served from a faster server, but that goes for anything web related. Throw it on better hardware to get better performance (for the most part).

If they are large images, you should first and foremost, optimize them. Make sure they are the smallest file size possible. Also, don't bother splitting "1.5mb" of them over to another host. Either upload them directly all through a CDN (some even tie into your WP Library, like Cloudinary), or keep them local to your site. You'll save yourself some headaches later.

If you have a photo heavy website (photography or other types of galleries), 3mb isn't really an awful lot - but again it's best to serve a more compressed image, you can even link the image or a button to the "full resolution" one.

Comment: Thanks for the great answer images are optimized.  unfortunately for this post, i need 86 images, cause that the type of post it is. Also, isnt Flickr on a CDN? Cloudflare CDN messes up my site, if thats the route then the i got to contact there customer technical support.  Lazy load flashes too, just keeps the holder though.